# Logs generation for process mining on a workflow model

Tags: logging, process, workflow, data-modeling, cpn-tools

I have a workflow model in paper format and i want to check its working in ProM, (the software for process mining). As ProM takes Event logs as input. But i have not event logs of that workflow model. How can i generate logs form that workflow model so that i may use them as input to Prom and generate PetriNet from it.

What I have tried:

1. [Technique mentioned here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia96fBucbSAhWI8RQKHcJmBXoQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.processmining.org%2F_media%2Ftools%2Fcpn05_cpnlogs_v2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFw3mdlNLsatvyzNJVZ3n3MHXSt-A) was tried by me, it uses CPN tools, but it only executes first transition of petrinet to generate logs from model. Only series of number are being generated
2. [Process Log Generator](http://plg.processmining.it/) was also tried by me. But it generates random logs

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your objectives? If you have a model and don't have any logs, you can use CPNTools to create a Petri Net model for simulation and you also can export it for using in ProM. But I think there is no much sense in analyzing a model in ProM without real event logs.

Comment: @Den Is there any other way except CPN tools. I am having many conditions in my model. And modeling it all in CPN tools is very much difficult. Please suggest

Comment: There are many commercial simulation tools like https://www.arenasimulation.com/ but I'm not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put activities and case-Id in a csv file and give it to ProM. 
For example, the following event log is corresponding to 4 cases.

```
case,event
1,g
1,m
1,b
1,d
1,a
1,e
2,c
2,d
2,a
2,n
2,d
2,a
2,e
3,c
3,a
3,d
3,e
4,g
4,m
4,b
4,a
4,d
4,n
4,a
4,d
4,e
5,c
5,d
5,a
5,n
5,a
5,d
5,e
```

Comment: Although it is very late answer, I used the same approach as you mentioned. But it is and was very difficult to generate logs using this approach. Because generated a few thousand logs using this approach ....:) very complicated and time consuming.

Comment: I just get it. if you have a petri net, you can use "Perform a simple simulation of a (stochastic) petri net" plug-in in ProM framework. you can adjust the number of traces and .... I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can design your Petri net using WoPeD. After that import the Petri net to ProM. Finally there are some simulation plugins that you can use them to simulate your event log e.g, "Perform a simple simulation of a (stochastic) petri net". 
Note that you should put a token in the source of the Petri net.